# Is there a pattern for 3x3 matrices for a specific determinant?

Tags: matrices

We were learning about matrices and determinants in school and I was wondering if there was a way to guarantee a specific determinant for a 3x3 matrix?

Comment: I mean, other than the formula for the determinant, not sure what you want. If the rows and/or columns aren't algebraically independent, the determinant will be 0

Comment: I'm just wondering if there was a pattern that would guarantee a specific determinant. Like if I want a determinant of 1 then there would be a pattern for the matrix.

Comment: The pattern is the formula. If there was a simpler pattern, there'd be a simpler formula

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The determinant of $\pmatrix{1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\\0&&0&&x}$ is $x$

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that it was that simple.

Comment: In 3D, the determinant is the volume of the parallelepiped where the three columns correspond to the edges of the parallelepiped (check out 3Blue1Brown's amazing [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk) on this). The determinant of the volume is thus $1 \cdot 1 \cdot x = x$.

Comment: But as long as your 3×3 matrix defines a rotation, reflection or shear in one direction I guess the determinant will be 1.